# VBA save Presentation as PDF in Handout 2x2 format Office 2007

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to save a PowerPoint presentation using VBA, and I want to save it as a .pdf in Handout format with 2x2 slides on a page. Can somebody tell me or point me to a link that tells me how to do it. I've done my homework on Google, but couldn't find it. Any help/suggestions/hints will be appreciated.

I've tried searching the reference too, but I only reached the `ppSaveAsPDF`, which is anyway accessible from the VBE IntelliSense. But I don't know how to achieve the handout 2x2 part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using `ActivePresentation.SaveAs`, which is not powerful enough. 
This did the job: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb231096.aspx

```
Sub CreateHandout()

ActivePresentation.ExportAsFixedFormat "Y:\ml\PDFs\" + Replace(ActivePresentation.name, "pptx", "pdf"), ppFixedFormatTypePDF, ppFixedFormatIntentPrint, msoCTrue, ppPrintHandoutHorizontalFirst, ppPrintOutputFourSlideHandouts, msoFalse, , , , False, False, False, False, False

End Sub
```

The editor helps you decide the correct options using IntelliSense.