# Controlling PowerPoint with Python's win32com. How to access "Save As" option programmatically

Tags: python, vba, client, powerpoint, win32com

I'm trying to open powerpoint via python and then save the slide presentation as pdf handouts (three to a page). After a bit of googling, I stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170830/vba-save-presentation-as-pdf-in-handout-2x2-format-office-2007). A pretty similar question. however, I can't seem to get it running. I think I may be 'translating' the VB into Python incorrectly.

Looking over the MSDN docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb231096.aspx), I attempted to fill in the two required arguments as a starting point. While it seems to accept the `path`, it throws an error with the `FixedFormatType`.

My code is as follows.

```
import win32com.client, sys, os

app = win32com.client.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")
app.Visible = True

names = []
for i in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if i[-1] == 't':
        tmp = os.getcwd() + '\\' + i
        names.append(tmp)
        tmp = ''



presentation = app.Presentations.Open(names[0])
presentation.ExportAsFixedFormat(os.getcwd() + '\\test.pdf', 'PpFixedFormatType')
```

I've tried many variations of the `ppFixdFormatType` argument. `ppFixedFormatTypePDF`, `win32com.ppFixedFormatTypePDF`, `win32com.client.constants.ppFixedFormatTypePDF`, etc.. but all raise an error of one type or another. Most are similar to this: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'PpFixedFormatType'`

Comment: I don't know python but try this `presentation.ExportAsFixedFormat(os.getcwd() + '\\test.pdf', 2)`

Comment: @SiddharthRout -- No luck :( I received the following error: `TypeError: The Python instance can not be converted to a COM object`

Comment: How about mentioning the rest of the parameters? `presentation.ExportAsFixedFormat(os.getcwd() + '\\test.pdf', 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, False, 1, False, False, False,False)` This is just an example. Change it as per your requirements.

Comment: @Siddharth Rout -- still no luck. That same COM object error gets thrown.

Comment: Have you tried searching for `The Python instance cannot be converted to a COM object` in Google?

Comment: @Siddharth Rout -- haha, yeah, and it was one of the first searches I've ever done that stumped Google. "No results found".

Comment: I just searched it myself & got these results https://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&gs_nf=1&pq=exportasfixedformat%20pdf%20powerpoint%20in%20python&cp=56&gs_id=4y6&xhr=t&q=the+python+instance+cannot+be+converted+to+a+com+object&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=The+Python+instance+can+not+be+converted+to+a+COM+object&aq=0s&aqi=g-s1&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=f39b2f5b2aa0605e&biw=1920&bih=890 :) Also see this link. It is about Word but will give you a basic idea http://code.google.com/p/gridfs-document-transformer-tools/source/browse/trunk/src/lib/GridDocTransform.py?spec=svn10&r=10

Comment: See the Green Section at the end of the code

Answer (score 1):

You may have encountered this bug in PowerPoint's API: [Type mismatch when using export function of PowerPoint 2007](http://sourceforge.net/p/pywin32/bugs/339/).
The solution is to specify the PrintRange parameter to the ExportAsFixedFormat() call.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is about manipulating PowerPoint through VBA, but you can save a PDF slides as a handout (like PowerPoint does) also using the free and open source [pdftools](https://github.com/raffaem/pdftools).

The commands to save a 3x3 handout would be:

```
pdftools --input-file slides.pdf --output slides_W.pdf --white-page --fitpaper --overwrite
pdftools --input-file slides_W.pdf --nup 3 3 --height 0.32 --delta 0mm 0mm --landscape --out-suffix _HANDOUT --frame --overwrite --paginate --paper a4paper -t $filename 0.4 0.01
```

You can obtain a different handout layout by manipulating the parameters passed to the `--nup` option