# Python win32com and Powerpoint ExportAsFixedFormat

Tags: python, com, powerpoint, ole, win32com

I'm trying to convert a .pptx file to .pdf using python and win32com. The code I'm using looks like this:

```
ppoint = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Powerpoint.Application")
ppoint.Visible = True
pres = ppoint.Presentations.Open(PPT_FILE_NAME)
pres.ExportAsFixedFormat(PDF_FILE_NAME, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, False, 1, False, False, False,False)
```

The problem is that ExportAsFixedFormat throws an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "converter.py", line 30, in 
>       pres.ExportAsFixedFormat(PDF_FILE_NAME2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, False, 1, False, Fal
>   se, False,False)
>     File "D:\applics\Python\lib\site-packages\win32com\gen_py\91493440-5A91-11CF-8
>   700-00AA0060263Bx0x2x11_Presentation.py", line 112, in ExportAsFixedFormat
>       , KeepIRMSettings, DocStructureTags, BitmapMissingFonts, UseISO19005_1, Exte
>   rnalExporter
>     File "D:\applics\Python\lib\site-packages\win32com\client__init__.py", line 4
>   59, in *ApplyTypes*
>       self.*oleobj*.InvokeTypes(dispid, 0, wFlags, retType, argTypes, *args),
>   TypeError: The Python instance can not be converted to a COM object

I am aware that I can use SaveAs as a workaround, but it is much less powerful than ExportAsFixedFormat. So the question is: how can I solve the error above?

I did come across [a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811480/controlling-powerpoint-with-pythons-win32com-how-to-access-save-as-option-pr) on StackOverflow, but the solution posted there doesn't help.

I'm using Python 3.3.2 and Office 2013, under Win7 x64.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using Office 2013 32- or 64-bit?  If 64-bit, try your code on a 32-bit install to see if it works there.  That'll narrow things down considerably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Bug in the PowerPoint API.

Workaround: Pass the keyword argument PrintRange=None.

For details see: https://sourceforge.net/p/pywin32/bugs/339/